# Design help for multi flavord app

Tags: android, oop

I am working on an app that is targeted at specific business partners and not consumers. At first, we had one main code base distinguished by many per client flavours only on trivial things like resources (would define a different main color and logo for each customer for example).

However over time different clients wanted different logic and we had to accommodate, so we factored out minor chunks of code to a "default behaviour" class which has a class extending it on each flavour, and so we could do minor changes per flavour.

The problem is over time the base behaviour class has become a monster, and refactoring is likely to break one flavour or another (there are about 30).

**So basically my question is:**

Can anyone think of a design solution that would scale to help manage an app with multiple flavours growing increasingly different in both UI and Logic, with minimal code duplication and easily maintainable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `BuildConfig` class. This is a static class created by *gradle* every time you build your app, which can be accessed in your app.

You declare them like this:

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        flavorX {
            buildConfigField("String", "Flavor", "\"flavorX\"")
        }
    }
}
```

And then in code you simply use

```
String flavor = BuildConfig.Flavor;
if(flavor.equals("flavorX")){
    //do stuff
}
```

`BuildConfig` is a static class, so this will allow you to make the flavor differentiation where it is needed, not in just one replaced class. This seems more efficient and more maintainable in your case.

Comment: we are already relying the BuildConfig class for various CONSTS that need replacing per flavour, however this is not a good option for a design because the code will just be filled with an enormous amount of  if/else if statements bulking up the main code base

Comment: Sure, but it is still better than replacing classes for 30 flavors. If you keep the code clean and all programmers are aware of this approach, this solution works really well :-) Also, it is worth it to write some Util class, like FlavorUtil.java, with methods like isFlavorX(), isPinkFlavor() etc., so all the equals logic and constants are kept in one place :-)